# How do I use the setDate() function on a date generated from a cursor?

Tags: date, meteor, between, getdate

How do I use the setDate() function on a date generated from a cursor?

I am trying to correctly generate a query that returns a cursor with values between the **One day before the expiry date** and the **expiry date itself**.

Find below my code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var expiryDate;      
var dayBeforeExpiry;  

var loopThruCollection = buyList.find({});  

loopThruCollection.forEach(function (row) {
        console.log (row.expiryDate)    
        expiryDate = row.expiryDate;            
});

 // expiryDate minus one day, should equal the day before the expiry date.
 dayBeforeExpiry = expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() -1);

 if(currentDate == dayBeforeExpiry){ 
      return buyList.find({ expiryDate : {'$gte': dayBeforeExpiry, '$lte': expiryDate } }).fetch();

      }     

 else { 
       return buyList.find({ expiryDate : {'$lte': expiryDate}} ).fetch(); 
      }
```

The results from the code above is:

```
Thu Mar 30 2017 16:29:35 GMT+0300 (EAT)
2017-02-22T14:46:33+03:00
2017-03-21T17:17:22+03:00
2017-03-21T17:18:45+03:00
2017-01-30T17:42:21+03:00
2017-02-22T15:10:50+03:00
2017-01-27T21:45:57+03:00

Uncaught TypeError: expiryDate.getDate is not a function(…)
```

I am not sure how I should go about generating the day before variable from the expiryDate.

Kindly point me in the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your output, it looks like not all your `expiryDate` fields are actually stored as `ISODate` in mongodb (since they are outputting differently).  If they are not stored as `ISODate` then they won't get mapped automatically to a `Date` object in Meteor.  This is most likely why you are getting your `.getDate is not a function(…)` error.

You can verify this by querying mongodb directly and looking at the stored values for your field.  Check and see if some are being stored as strings vs. `ISODate`.  I'm betting some are strings and some are `ISODate`.

Also, you cannot use equality operators (e.g. `==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`) to compare the value of javascript dates, because that is actually comparing the objects themselves (not their value) and it will always be `false`.  Per the [javascript comparison operators reference docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=test)...

> An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.

You should compare the value of dates using the `.getTime()` method instead.

```
// won't work...will always return false
if (currentDate == dayBeforeExpiry) { 
  // do stuff
}

// correct way
if (currentDate.getTime() == dayBeforeExpiry.getTime()) { 
  // do stuff
}
```

However, even this may not do what you are wanting because the comparison is down to the millisecond.  It might make more sense for you to change your logic and compare the year, month, and day only and exclude time altogether.

With that said, I would highly recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in your meteor app to handle all your date logic.  It has built in functions to add/subtract units of time and compare dates.  I deal with dates a lot in my app and I find using it a life saver.

You can install it in your meteor app via npm (`meteor npm install moment --save`) or as a meteor package (`meteor add momentjs:moment`).

Comment: A couple of remarks: 1. You probably don't ever want to compare dates using equality (or strict equality operators), as if you miss it by a millisecond, they times won't be equal. I would guess that the OP wants to set some kind of a reminder and chooses the naiive path for it. 2. `moment.js`, as well as other libraries, is also installable via npm in any recent version of Meteor.

Comment: Yup that is true regarding equality.  I only showed it as an example to directly tie back to the OPs code.  You are correct about npm in Meteor as well.  I will update that.